# Lodash FP curry + TypeScript - loosing type information

Tags: typescript, functional-programming, lodash, option-type

I'm trying to implement simple Maybe functor in TypeScript:

```js
type Maybe<T> = T | null;

function mapMaybe<T, T2>(fn: (value: T) => T2, maybe: Maybe<T>): Maybe<T2> {
  if (input === null) return null;
  return fn(input);
}
```

that works fine - see [the Playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#code/C4TwDgpgBAsghiARhAPAFQHxQLxTVAHygDsBXAG3IG4BYAKHoDNTiBjYASwHtioBbOGHhJUaADR4ATBgAUjYgC4oMgG5xypCErQBKHFjSSJAkUuHJ0GHWYQXDWAN70oUDo2UnkObLjKU9AE4QwKQBvH7UzlBBIWFQ8jKeEDq0dAC+9PSsPADOwPyCkAAmNiIoeQEcxADmWLgCQrYQMjIA7lwBRTlKAIIBAQjlwJU1VvpQ7Z05AHQAVlxVMgBEUEs6EgDaSwDqHJRLEkvAABYcOQerkwDWAPxLALo69AD0z1AAtO9YO3vkUCdnCYdW5LLK5fINYqSUoWCpVWo4AqNEQtSZdXr9QZw0Z6bBYNEzeaLFZrCQRJ50V4fL4kCjkMHEPITAI8aow1DYhH1QTmZptDroqB9AYgIYjWq4-ECwkLYjLVbrKCSSQUqmfAAeQoC1VIfAgxHyXHcoEgUAA5Mqza4ciQuPk4DkchxqsQ4IhyNBgFwoGA4AM9cAIAEoEb-uBoGbeWL4Rt7hgzdNMnRsoyuB7puQuNVEoUIEUKSmcmmIBmszmwFCdEA.).

Now I also want to have the mapping function curried so that I can nicely compose it. I use Lodash FP, so this is what I'm trying:

```js
export const mapMaybe = _.curry(function<T, T2>(
  fn: (arg: T) => T2,
  maybe: Maybe<T>
): T2 | null {
  if (maybe === null) return null;
  return fn(maybe);
});
```

This works as expected at runtime, but I'm loosing type information and even if I mess up, compiler does not warn me. According to TS the type of my curried function is

```js
const mapMaybe: (...args: any[]) => any
```

so if I write this code (note a mismatch between the function `(value: Array<string>) => string` and the value in the maybe `number`):

```js
const mapped: Maybe<string> = mapMaybe((words: Array<string>) => words.join(" "), 22)
```

I get no errors from the compiler - only at runtime  Is there any way I can get my precious compile-time errors back?

Comment: can you share the type definition for lodash curry function?

Comment: @MaciejSikora I'm using definitions from Definitely Typed. If you follow all the references it's quite a lot (too much to paste here), but here is the starting point: https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/f05ea21c9dbbed879b0e90aa0173310ef7c0aab1/types/lodash/fp.d.ts#L4652